# Determine penalty parameter based on AIC values in lasso regression for linear mixed model

Tags: r, lasso, model, mixed-model

I have a dataset with 14 variables, of which one random effect (Patient)
I fitted following code:

"fit1_B2=lmmlasso(y=y,x=x.matrix,z=z,grp=grp,lambda=0.1,pdMat="pdIdent")
summary(fit1_B2)
fit1_B2$aic"

I have, however, chosen the penalty parameter at random. The purpose is to obtain the penalty parameter that minimizes the AIC value.

Does anyone have an idea how this might be done?

Many thanks in advance.

Pieter

Answer (score -1):

For a Lasso model, we try different penalty of lambda to find the best model, trading off the variance and bias to minimize a validation error.

AIC is an indicator of single discrete models, which we can define the p (number of parameters) clearly.
However, for a lasso model, we can not define "p" clearly and it is a smooth weighted model. This is the advantage of Lasso.

So we can not minimize the AIC, but should minimize the validation error by separating the data set into training and validating set, or cross-validation.